# Manutenção em banco de dados c#

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho um sistema em outra linguagem e preciso criar um atualizador para esse sistema, porém precisa ser rodado Scripts em MySQL para a manutenção do banco de dados.

Pesquisei em Java e achei o Maven que tem todo esse controle de manutenção e lê os Scripts escrito em SQL. Em c# o mais perto que consegui chegar foi o code First migrations, porém não achei nenhum exemplo onde o mesmo executasse Scripts SQL.

Minha grande dúvida é se consigo fazer isso com *migrations*, se não, existe outro jeito de fazer isso em C#?

Comment: você falar em fazer um sistema e a parti dele fazer alteração como inclusão de novos campos ou deletar campos existentes ? se for , sim o Code First faz isso .

Comment: A ideia do code first não é fazer manutenção de um banco de dados baseado em script e sim em um modelo de dados (classes).

Answer (score 1):

Vou te passar como faço em um sistema, que não trabalha com nenhum Framwork ORM:

Na base de dados cliente, tenho uma chave:

```
last_upd_sql
```

que armazeno o código da última atualização do banco de dados que foi recebida.

No servidor, tenho uma tabela:

```
id|descricao|script|data|etc...
```

onde insiro cada script que deve ser executado na base cliente.

Um `WebService`, que recebe como parâmetro, o id da última atualização que o cliente recebeu, e retorna um `XML` com todos os comandos posteriores a esse id.

O sistema cliente, consome esse `WebService` enviando o valor do `last_upd_sql` em seguida processa cada comando recebido pelo `XML` atualizando o valor de `last_upd_sql`.

Esse sistema funciona há alguns anos e nunca tive problemas.